# R loop on names and variables

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, merge, rename

So I have this data set with multiple lines for each person, which represents the same type of event that happened for each individual. Each person could have up to 39 times this event. What I am trying to do is put all these events in a single line for each person. Now each event has multiple variables attached to it. My goal is to have for instance all the variables for the first event called A1, B1, C1 etc.... And then the ones for the second event would be A2, B2, C2 etc... And onwards. So I was thinking that the best way around this would be to create a separate file for each Number of event, so each first event is in the same file, each second is in the second etc... Then I would rename all the variables with the proper number in their names, and finally I would re-merge everything together.

So I was thinking that the best way to do this is with a for loop, but I can't seem to make it work.

This is my current code

```
for (i in 2:39){
  sentence[i]_prison <- sentence_prsubset[which(sentence_prsubset$order_sentence==[i])]
  sentence[i]_prison <- rename(sentence[i]_prison, 
                            c(difftime_SB[i]days="difftime_SBdays",
                              difftime_SB(i)weeks="difftime_SBweeks",
                              difftime_SB(i)fnight="difftime_SBfnight",
                              difftime_SB(i)fnrnum="difftime_SBfnrnum",
                              difftime_SE(i)days="difftime_SEdays",
                              difftime_SE(i)weeks="difftime_SEweeks",
                              difftime_SE(i)fnight="difftime_SEfnight",
                              difftime_SE(i)fnrnum="difftime_SEfnrnum"))
   sentence(i)_prison <- subset(sentence(i)_prison, select=-c(order_sentence)) }
```

Currently I am getting an `unexpected token' error. I tried just the first line of the for loop but that doesn't work either, I still have that error. I tried putting the i in [i] or (i) but that didn't work. I really want to have the number in the middle of the variable names.

I have yet to add the merge in the code since in every case the code is not working properly. But why can't I do this, how can I do this better, and is this possible.

I have done this previously with Stata, but I can't seem to get around how R works with this type of for loop.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Having the subsetting index embedded in the object name does not work in R. You need to place it at the end of the object. Executing a comparison against `[i]` is also not something I have seen in R. This code will not work:

```
sentence[i]_prison <- sentence_prsubset[which(sentence_prsubset$order_sentence==[i])]
```

As a general suggestion: create a data frame or tibble with two columns: the person name and the event. Both strings I would expect.
Then group by name (`dplyr` `group_by`) and use the `tidyr` function `pivot_wider` to change to a wide data object.